# My menu hides behind DIV . t will be hides or not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello i am create a master pages. in a Master page i create a Dropdown menu with jquery and css it is working fine in some pages but hides in some page those  pages contain a div.it is working underneath of div so it is not visibile in some pages.here i am attach the CSS and HTML code.in case of master page menu is  working fine but apply .aspx page is working but it hides inside a div.

```
body
{
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#nav, #nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#nav a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
     background: #595651;
}

#nav a:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
    background: #F86000;
}

#nav li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#nav ul
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 12em;
    top: 1.5em;
}

#nav li ul a
{
    width: 12.8em;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

#nav ul ul
{
    top: auto;
}

#nav li ul ul
{
    left: 12em;
    margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul
{
    display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

Language: lang-html

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="adminmenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_adminmenu" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../MainStyles/Menu3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../Jquery/jquery-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../Jquery/menu.js"></script>
    <link href="../MainMenucss/MaimSlideMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">Operation</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Transmittal Operations</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New Internal Transmittal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">New External Transmittal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Issued Deliverables(External Docs)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Non Deliverable Transmittal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Transmittal logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">General Document Manager</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forward Transmittal Mails</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Editor Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hard Copy management</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Hard Copy Issue Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Master</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">General Metadata</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Phase Specific MetaData</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Permission settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use z-index property in css to manage the order of the elements stack, that is which element should appear on top of the other, give the element you want to appear on top a higher value.

```
div { z-index: 500;}
ul { z-index: 1000;}
```

This will make the ul element appear on top of the div element if they overlap.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can set z-index value to set order in which elements are stacked on screen.

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.

Read complete article on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

```css
#nav,
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
#nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #595651;
}
#nav a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  background: #F86000;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 12em;
  top: 1.5em;
}
#nav li ul a {
  width: 12.8em;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
#nav ul ul {
  top: auto;
}
#nav li ul ul {
  left: 12em;
  margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
}
#nav li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul ul ul,
#nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul,
#nav li li:hover ul,
#nav li li li:hover ul,
#nav li li li li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#nav li > ul {
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="">Operation</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Transmittal Operations</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">New Internal Transmittal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New External Transmittal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Issued Deliverables(External Docs)</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Non Deliverable Transmittal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Transmittal logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">General Document Manager</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Forward Transmittal Mails</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Editor Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Hard Copy management</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hard Copy Issue Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```